# basic http authentication tomcat not working

Tags: tomcat, authentication, basic-authentication

I use tomcat 7 and I want to use http basic authentication. If you want to access a site, you are forced to type in a username and password.

my url: `http://localhost:8080/project`

But i want to provide the username and password in the url. I want to skip the window where I have to write username and password. Like it is described http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

wiki example: `https://username:password@www.example.com/path`

In my case it should be something like the following:

```
 username = admin
 password = mypw1#

https://admin:mypw1#@localhost:8080/project
```

or

```
http://admin:mypw1#@localhost:8080/project
```

But it is not working. Neither in Firefox nor in Chrome. Browser can't even find the site. If I just use `localhost:8080/project` the site is loaded and I am prompted to login with username and password.

Comment: Is Tomcat configured for `SSL` ?

Comment: It's a default installation. No changes to server.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser uses `#` for the anchor. You have to escape the hash or use HTTP auth header.

Answer (score 1):

Try [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the password:

```
http://admin:mypw1%23@localhost:8080/project
```